# How to set up a driver to change value from zero to one every frame

Tags: drivers

I want to figure out how to set up up drivers that alternate from zero to one every frame. Id also love to know how to do it if i wanted to alternate every 4 frames or possibly value 1 for 4 frames and value 0 for 2 frames or so.

These are the types of patterns i want to know how to create

01010101, 00100100

Comment: you can do it like this: "frame % 2" (paste this is the drivers field). this other one is "(frame+2) % 3 > 1"

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your answer Chris, it was only one small change away from being complete.

Answer (score 10):

**Python console.**

Further to other answers, will elaborate on  using the python console to test driver expressions

For a 1 every Nth frame, using modulus as elaborated on in other answers,

```
not frame % N
```

which is the equivalent of

```
frame % N == 0
```

Test run in the console, `f` for frame. A boolean when used in an expression is converted to an integer. 1 is True.

```
>>> for f in range(1, 10):
...     f, f % 4, int(not f % 2), int(not f % 3), int(not f % 4)
...     
(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(2, 2, 1, 0, 0)
(3, 3, 0, 1, 0)
(4, 0, 1, 0, 1)
(5, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(6, 2, 1, 1, 0)
(7, 3, 0, 0, 0)
(8, 0, 1, 0, 1)
(9, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

replace N with a number for your driver expression, eg every 4th

```
not frame % 4
```

*Note this can be typed directly into the property field. Prefix the expression with  hash `#` the first time eg `#not frame % 4` to signify it as a driver (turns purple on entering).*

Since these are booleans, every 4th or every 13th

```
not frame % 4 or not frame % 13
```

For a repeating pattern `000011` it may be simpler to shift the frame to make frame 1 calculate as 0

```
>>> for f in range(1, 10):
...     f, (f - 1) % 6, int((f - 1) % 6 > 3)
...     
(1, 0, 0)
(2, 1, 0)
(3, 2, 0)
(4, 3, 0)
(5, 4, 1)
(6, 5, 1)
(7, 0, 0)
(8, 1, 0)
(9, 2, 0)
```

Expression

```
(frame - 1) % 6 > 3
```

which is the same as

```
 (frame - 1) % 6 // 4
```

using mods partner in crime to integer divide modulus result by 4. Only 4 and 5 will produce 1.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using the frame number, there are two ways you can create the driver.

The easier way is to go to the input field that you want the driver attached to and type in a python expression, using **#frame** to represent the frame number.

The harder way is to go to the input field that you want the driver attached to, right click, and select Add Driver.  In this case you use **frame** without the '#' character.  Delete the existing 'var' entry and type the python expression into the Expression input.

I'm going to type *frame* in the expressions below.  Substitute **#frame** if you're typing into the input field; Substitute **frame** if you're in the driver editor.

The trick is to use Python's *mod* operator, which is represented by the percent sign (%) in Python.  Mod returns the remainder after an integer division.  If you type **7 % 3**, python will return 1, since 7 divided by 3 is 2, but 2 * 3 is 6, so 7 - 6 = 1.

The other thing to know is that Python uses 0 to represent false and 1 to represent true, so logical expressions in Python, such as **x > y** return integer values.

If you want to generate a repeating sequence of N zeros followed by a 1, you can use the following expression *frame % (N + 1) > 0*.  This is because the mod operator only returns 0 when the number is exactly divisible by the second operand.

Alternating 0s and 1s is a special case, since the mod operator only returns 0 or 1 when 2 is the second operator, so, putting this all together,

for alternating 0 and 1, use ***frame* % 2**.  For two 0s followed by a 1, use ***frame* % 3 > 0** as your expression:

As an immediate driver:

[image: directly typed in driver]

As an expression in the driver editor:

[image: as an expression in the driver editor]

Comment: Note: If you add an immediate driver, using #frame; when you left click on the field again, blender will show you the expression _without_ the #.  This explains why my first screen shot showed an obviously working driver with what appears to be an invalid expression.

Comment: Why the downvote?