# Driver to change the seed every 4 frames? (Replicating "Step" Function in LineArt Modifier)

Tags: modifiers, drivers, lineart

I am trying to work out an easy, repeatable solution to [this question:](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/skbfjg/i_get_a_flickering_problem_with_the_line_art_and/)

I am using Line Art in Blender 4.0, not freestyle, but the problem persists.

I am trying to use a driver on the Noise Seed in the Noise Modifier to give it a random/value every 4 frames. I want this to be editable, pretty much recreating the "Randomize" option below it. I have used keyframes to get the result I want by changing the seed value every 4 frames with constant interpolation, but want a simple driver command to simplify/recreate this. The closest I have gotten is "(frame - 1) % 6 // 4" from this [This Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235677/how-to-set-up-a-driver-to-change-value-from-zero-to-one-every-frame?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

However, my understanding of drivers/python is incredibly limited. Would be fantastic to get some kind of help here with a solution/possible description to increase my understanding of the process. Thank you.

[image: The Keyframe Solution]

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is a frame challenge.)

Don't use a driver expression. Use fcurve modifiers.

1. Set a keyframe on the Seed property.
2. Open the keyframe editor.
3. Add a Noise modifier to the fcurve and scale up the strength (to $1000$). [Set the Scale property to an odd value with decimal places to circumvent the artefacts of pseudo-random noise.]
4. Add a Generator modifier to the fcurve and use the coefficients $500$ (for x^0) and $0$ for x^1. This shifts the curves and prevents negative values. (The seed can't be negative.)
5. Add a Stepped modifier and set the step size to $4$.

[image: stepped random value]

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. I will give this a go, am probably going to use the floor driver listed above for most of my solutions but this seems far more versatile and a good exercise for me to undertake.

Answer (score 0):

Try `floor(frame / 4)`.

(Note that `frame // 4` is substantially the same, but is a "Slow Python Expression", so is to be avoided.)

Comment: Sorry for a the late reply, thanks a ton for this addition. I think for my scenario this is the answer I am looking for. Thank you